# How is Array.IndexOf implemented in c#?

Tags: c#, implementation

I have looked for it but can't seem to find it anywhere. Can anybody help me? I need to use it but it doesn't exist in Visual Studio for my Mac, so it would be pretty helpful.

Comment: .net core: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Array.cs#L964 but it should be available for mac

Comment: It is part of the core System namespace. Did you include the `System` with `using System;` ?

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean this?

```
string [] aBunchOfWords = new string[] {
            "hey", "check", "out", "this", "bunch", "of", "words"
        }; 
        int whereMyWordIs = Array.IndexOf(aBunchOfWords, "this"); 
        Console.WriteLine(whereMyWordIs);
```

Comment: Just wondering: why are people downvoting this answer? OP asked for where IndexOf was in C# and he noted that it's `Array.IndexOf` with a code snippet that works.

Comment: The question is "How is `Array.IndexOf` *implemented* in c#?" and this answers "How to *use* `Array.IndexOf`". Complete lack of explanation and being answer to totally different question seem like a good possible reasons why it can be downvoted.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that makes sense. The original question was poorly worded and confused me so I wasn't sure what the OP was after TBH. "I need to use it but it doesn't exist in Visual Studio for my Mac, so it would be pretty helpful" <- to me, that kind of sounds like the OP just wants to **use** `IndexOf` but doesn't know how. I don't know. Anyway, thank you.